# MVC Viewmodel partially null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My View is bound to this model

```
 public class HomepageViewModel
{
    public HomepageViewModel()
    {
        Regions = new List<TMRegion>();
    }

    public List<TMRegion> Regions { get; set; }

    public int SelectedRegion { get; set; }

    public SelectList SelectListRegions
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var tmRegion in Regions)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = tmRegion.Value.ToString(),
                    Text = tmRegion.Display
                });
            }
            return new SelectList(items);
        }
    }
}
```

My view is like this -

```
@model ProSell.Admin.Models.ViewModels.HomepageViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { viewModel = Model }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Regions)


    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRegion, Model.SelectListRegions.Items as List<SelectListItem>, "Select a region")

<input type="submit"/>
```

}

My controller populates Regions like this -

```
 // GET: Search
    public async Task<ViewResult> Index(HomepageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.Regions.Count == 0)
        {
            viewModel = new HomepageViewModel();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            viewModel.Regions = 
                js.Deserialize<TMRegion[]>(
                    await _ApiConsumer.ExecuteGetMethod("myurlinhere"))
                    .ToList();

        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The Drop down is populated in the view. When i select a region and submit the HomepageViewModel  has the SelectedRegion correctly set to whatever id was selected, but the collection of Regions is empty.

How do I maintain the list in the model on submit?

Comment: Try removing `new { viewModel = Model }`, you shouldn't need this for the form data to submit to the controller.

Comment: You cannot binding a collection of complex objects to an `<input>` - look at the html its generating to understand! Do not attampt to post back the collection - if you need it (and the only time you do is if `ModelState` is invalid and you need to return the view) then get it again. And change the model to`public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListRegions { get; set; }`  - Its the responsibility of the controller to populate it, not the model

Comment: And there is no point casting the `SelectList` to `List<SelectListItem>` - you view just needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRegion, Model.SelectListRegions, "Select a region")

Comment: @RyanSearle, Fortunately for OP, `new { viewModel = Model }` is adding an (invalid) html attribute, not a route value otherwise nothing would be working :)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I've been living in an API/SPA world for the last couple of years, it's been a while since I've used MVC. That's cleared things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should attempt to reduce the amount of data the client sends back to the server especially with collections since it's far more efficient for the server to make a database call to retrieve the collection than have it passed back with the form data.

As Stephen said you can re-populate the collections `Regions` from your controller or if you need it when returning the view due to `ModelState` error you can add the population code into your model's constructor.

Also you can clean up your collection property like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListRegions
{
    get
    {
        return Regions.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.Display,
            Value = x.Value.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

and in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRegion, Model.SelectListRegions, "Select a region")
```